# Where to place @EnableBatchProcessing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using `spring-batch` for job executions. Does it matter on which class I place the `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)` annotation?

I would place it on the global `ApplicationConfig`, or would it be better to put it on the modular batch configuration where the batch job execution context is created? Eg:

```
@Configuration
public class ModularBatchConfig {
    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory myJob() {
       return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(MyJob.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an "application" that contains multiple batch jobs, we recommend putting the `@EnableBatchProcessing` at the highest level that makes sense.  What I mean by that is that `@EnableBatchProcessing` is going to bootstrap a number of common components (`JobRepository`, `TransactionManager`, etc).  It's typically better to use these as common components instead of bootstrapping one per job.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? In my case I have indeed has multiple batch jobs. There is just one globale `@Configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration` class, and one for the modular batch config. Where would you recommend adding the `@EnabelBatchProcessing(modular = true)`?

Comment: Same place as the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is.